# I am using firebase database and react. Datatable search is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement search functionality to datatable. Sometimes it works, and sometime doesn't. Something is wrong with it. I am not sure what am I doing wrong and what needs to be done here to be the searching option working properly.
Here is my data table code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#example").DataTable({
    bDestroy: true,
    ordering: false,
    search: {
      return: true,
    },
  });
});
```

And here is the whole code,

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
//Bootstrap and jQuery libraries
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
//Datatable Modules
import "datatables.net-dt/js/dataTables.dataTables";
import "datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css";
import $ from "jquery";
import { useFetchData } from "../../Hooks/useFetchData";
import firebase from "../../firebase";
import { collection, query, onSnapshot, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

import "./dataTable.css";

const DataTable = () => {
  const userId = localStorage.getItem("UserId");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  const db = firebase.firestore();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const q = await query(collection(db, "orders"));
      await onSnapshot(
        q,
        (querySnapshot) => {
          setOrders(
            querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
              id: doc.id,
              data: doc.data(),
            }))
          );
        },
        []
      );
    };
    fetchData();
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#example").DataTable({
        bDestroy: true,
        ordering: false,
        search: {
          return: true,
        },
      });
    });
  }, [db]);

  const empty = document.getElementsByClassName("dataTables_empty");
  for (let i = 0; i < empty.length; i++) {
    empty[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <table id="example" className="display table-container table_wd">
          <thead className="table_head">
            <tr>
              <th>Order Id</th>
              <th>Order Date</th>
              <th>Order Price</th>
              <th>Order Status</th>
              <th>View Details</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {orders.map((item) => {
              if (item.data.userId === userId) {
                console.log(item);
                const date = new Date(item.data.pickDate);
                const date_date = date.toLocaleDateString();
                return (
                  <tr className="table_row">
                    <td className="table_d">{item.data.orderID}</td>
                    <td className="table_d">{date_date}</td>
                    <td className="table_d">{item.data.amount}</td>
                    <td className="table_d">{item.data.orderStatus}</td>
                    <td className="table_d" style={{ color: "#04A9C7" }}>
                      <button
                        className="detail-button"
                        onClick={() => {
                          navigate("/orderDetails", { state: item.id });
                        }}
                      >
                        ViewDetails
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                );
              }
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataTable;
```

While writing something in the input field, it goes blank and returns a result that says, no data found. I want to filter my data based on order id by typing the id into the input box.